# RenderTargetBitmap messes up the WebView scaling

Tags: xaml, webview, windows-10, win-universal-app, rendertargetbitmap

I have a very simple repro case of RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync overload messing up the WebView scaling. All I have on the MainPage is a WebView and a button:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WebView Source="http://bing.com"></WebView>
    <Button Content="Render me"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
</Grid>
```

In code behind there's only a simple event handler

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await rtb.RenderAsync(this, 1280, 720);
}
```

This is what the page looks like before RenderAsync call:

[image: Before RenderAsync]

and this is what happens after the call:

[image: After RenderAsync]

Any idea why and how to prevent this? Note that it only happens if I call

```
await rtb.RenderAsync(this, 1280, 720);
```

but NOT if I call the overload without the scaling

```
await rtb.RenderAsync(this);
```

EDIT: Due to the first answer I received, I wanted to clarify why the aspect ratio is not the problem here, but only serves the purpose of proving that there actually is a problem. Think of the following scenario - very high DPI screen where only a lower resolution screenshot is needed - even if you scale it down with the RIGHT ratio, it still messes up the WebView. Also, for my scenario, resizing the screenshot manually afterwards is not an option - the RenderAsync overload with scaled dimensions is much much faster and I would really prefer to use that method.

Comment: Of course this is a bug, the only workaround is an small flickering thing 
            MainWebView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            await Task.Delay(10);
            MainWebView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

Comment: @JuanPabloGarciaCoello thanks, you and Pieter both suggested a similar solution. :)

Comment: Why manually resizing the bitmap isn't an option for you? If you are doing it from the foreground (not a `XamlRenderingBackgroundTask`) you could use GPU accelerated approaches like Win2D to do it very fast.

Comment: The WinComposition team is making a new get brush from the UIElement (that's what I interpreted) but I think until the Build we won't have news so as every year our minds will blow with all the APIs news. Might be then is also solved that bug.

Comment: Also I remember this WebViewBrush, I have never used it and it is funny it says in the comments that is not supported in Windows Phone and content will not be captured (screenshot I understand) Have you tried this to be sure?

Answer (score 1):

Very strange behavior...
I found one very dirty (!) fix to this. I basically hide and show the webview (wv) again.

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await rtb.RenderAsync(wv, 1280, 720);
    wv.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    await Task.Delay(100);
    wv.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

I'm not proud of this solution and the webview flashes, but at least it's not 'blown up' any more...

Comment: Thanks Pieter, that really does seem to make a difference but unfortunately for my scenario this really isn't a solution. :( Upvoting, but hoping that there will be other ideas...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack too, but I found that if you set the contents of another control through a `WebViewBrush` and then render that control, then the source `WebView` doesn't get any scaling. I have modified the XAML you provided so it looks like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border x:Name="Target" Width="1280" Height="720" />
    <WebView x:Name="webView"  Source="http://bing.com" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></WebView>

    <Button Content="Render me" Grid.Row="1"
        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />

</Grid>
```

In your case, you should opt to set the `Border` control behind your `WebView` (however, *don't* change its `Visibility` or put it outside of the window bounds, as `RenderAsync` will fail). Then, on the code behind, set the `Background` of the target control to an instance of a `WebViewBrush` that feeds on the `WebView`:

```
    private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebViewBrush brush = new WebViewBrush();
        brush.SetSource(webView);
        Target.Background = brush;
        Target.InvalidateMeasure();
        Target.InvalidateArrange();

        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await rtb.RenderAsync(Target, 1280, 720);
        var pixels = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
    }
```

You will get your final image without any issues caused to the source `WebView` (however, note that the final image will look distorted since the aspect ratios don't match). However this comes with a few caveats, the most important one being that the `WebView` size must match the one of the `RenderTargetBitmap` or you will get empty areas.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fixed values, use `VisibleBounds` to get the current window size.

Here's the code:

```
private async void pressMe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var windowBounds = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().VisibleBounds;
    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await rtb.RenderAsync(this, (int)windowBounds.Width, (int)windowBounds.Height);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about that, which is why I used a random size on purpose to demonstrate the effect. The other reason is that the problem also occurs if you try to scale down an image on high DPI screens. And, even if the result image gets messed up (I would expect that if the ratio is wrong), I wouldn't expect the WebView content to get messed up.

Comment: Thought you were looking for quick fix. You're very right; it shouldn't affect the view even if aspect ratio doesn't match. Seems like `RenderAsync()` scales the view itself before rendering it.